# if com condição console.log?

Tags: javascript

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer um if cuja condição é o resultado de um console.log 
Porém não tenho ideia de como fazer a comparação pois sou iniciante em JavaScript, seria mais ou menos assim??
Pois sempre retorna a condição true :(

```
      if(console.log(ev.target.tagName) == DIV)}
        alert("O log retornou DIV");
      } else {
        alert("O log retornou IMG");
      }
```

Comment: Porque não verificar direto o valor if(ev.target.tagName == "DIV") ?

Comment: Deu certo @Caique, obrigado e desculpe pela ignorância

Comment: Não tem porque se desculpar o site e para tirar dúvidas mesmo. Todos os dias aprendemos algo novo. Respondi sua pergunta la em baixo para complementar o meu comentário.

Comment: Perfeito!! Vlwww

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `console.log()` serve para mostrar algo no console do navegador.

Faça sua condição sem o console.log que deve funcionar, dessa forma:

```
  if(ev.target.tagName == 'DIV')}
    alert("O log retornou DIV");
  } else {
    alert("O log retornou IMG");
  }
```

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, deu certo !! Obrigado @Diego

Answer (score 4):

O console.log não dá retorno.

Tens de usar o `console.log` separado da lógica do código. Incluir na lógica do código é guardar trabalho para mais tarde pois vais ter que tirar e podes criar bugs nesse passo.

Testa assim:

```
const tagDiv = ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div';
console.log('É div?', tagDiv);
if(tagDiv}
    alert("O log retornou DIV");
} else {
    alert("O log retornou IMG");
}
```

Comment: Certo, entendi !!
Muito grato @Sergio :DD

Answer (score 1):

O **Javascript** possui algumas formas de Display, o `Console.log()` é uma delas.

> Console.log()
>   Escreve no console do navegador, é utilizado para propósitos de debug(depuração do código), recebe um único parâmetro sendo ele o valor a exibir no console.

Resumindo ele é utilizado para exibir apenas, o que você deve fazer é comparar o conteúdo que pretende exibir fora do `console.log`, manter toda a lógica fora dele.

```js
var x =1; //Declaro a variavel x e atribuo o valor 1 a ela.
var y =2; //Declaro a variavel y e atribuo o valor 2 a ela.

if(x+y == 3){ //se a condição for igual a 3 então exibo o texto:
  console.log("Verdadeiro, a soma é igual a 3!")
}

console.log(x+y); //Exibo a soma..
```

Comment: Entendi!! obg !!